# send and read string between threads

Tags: c++, string, sockets, buffer

This has been killing me and my lack of experience with c/c++ is the reason.

I cannot figure out how to read a string in from another thread. In this case the thread is coming from a client who is connected to a server thread. I have been able to pass ints without any problem. Can't seem to figure out how to get strings passed however.

client side who reads in the string from the console and needs to send to server:

```
cout << "Enter in an operation and number: \n ";
int x;
char str[20];
int len = strlen(str);
int result;


cin>>str;
cin>>x;

write(client_sock, &len, sizeof(int));
write(client_sock, str, len);
write(client_sock, &x, sizeof(x));

read(client_sock, &result, sizeof(result));
cout<<result;
```

server side that needs to read string, for testing I am trying to send it back however I need to read it in and compare it to other conditions to carryout operations on the numbers I read in.

```
int result;
int input;
int len;
char str;

read(client_sock, &input, sizeof(input));
read(client_sock,&len,sizeof(len));
char buf[sizeof(len)];
sscanf(buf, "%s", &str);

cout<<str;
result= input*input;

write(client_sock,&result,sizeof(result));
write(client_sock, buf, strlen(buf));
```

of course this is an assignment, my professor told me to read in characters into a buffer and null terminate it. I am not sure what he means by null terminating.. also am i correctly reading into the buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are some pointers

you need to do the same steps both when you write and read

e.g. write the length (number of bytes) of the string first on the socket, i guess in your case a single byte should suffice to describe the length, after that write the string as a series of bytes. If you want have larger strings use a data type for the length that is well defined and not `int`, for instance do your own type and bear in mind that if you are communicating between platforms you may need to consider [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

what you have so far on the writing side seems ok (i guess you left out the opening/binding etc of the sockets):

```
write(client_sock, &len, sizeof(unsigned char));
write(client_sock, str, len);
```

on the receiver side you first read the length, then that number of following bytes:

```
read(client_sock, &len, sizeof(unsigned char));
char* buffer = new char[len + 1]; // create a buffer
read(client_sock, buffer, len);
buffer[len]='\0'; // terminate the string
```

now you got the string in buffer, just convert it to a std::string.

```
std::string s = buffer;
delete [] buffer;
```

*[ disclaimer : not intended to code complete or compilable just to show principle ]*

these are incorrect statements:

```
char buf[sizeof(len)];
sscanf(buf, "%s", &str);
```

buf is uninitialized and too small since `sizeof(len)` will return the size of an `int` only and you are practically reading from an uninitialized buffer into a string that has space for one byte. there is no need for sscanf here.

Answer (score 0):

a null-terminated string is a standard c string ... a series of chars, followed by a null byte

as a plain ascii string "Hello" would look like

0x48 (H)
0x65 (e)
0x6c (l)
0x6c (l)
0x6f (o)
0x00 (NULL)

as you can see, you need a buffer that is your string length + 1 byte (the null terminator)

Comment: thanks but that barely helps me.. would i just set the buffer size to buf[sizeof(len)+1] ... len being the size of the string read in

Answer (score 0):

A few comments:

```
cout << "Enter in an operation and number: \n ";
int x;
char str[20];
int len = strlen(str);
int result;
```

I don't know about C++, but C will not automatically zero your memory for you. Your `char str[20] ; int len = strlen(str);` is running `strlen(3)` on *random* memory. It might contain a string. It might contain function pointers from the previous call stack. It certainly contains garbage, and calling `strlen()` on it is also going to generate garbage -- maybe even a segmentation violation.

```
char str;
/* ... */
char buf[sizeof(len)];
sscanf(buf, "%s", &str);
```

Again, you've allocated a character buffer and immediately hand it, uninitialized, to `sscanf(3)`. `sscanf(3)` is going to be reading garbage and nothing it does can possibly be correct.

Furthermore, you're trying to store a *string* into a single byte (`char str`). You need to (a) change `char str` to `char *str` (b) actually allocate some memory for it. But maybe the `strdup(3)` function would be more useful, since this looks like you're just trying to duplicate the string.